# Remove controllers from UINavigationController stack

Tags: objective-c, ios

I can't figure out why FirsViewController is not destroyed/releasedd in this scenario.

My AppDelegate.m - FirstViewController is pushed on the stack

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];

self.FirstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc]
                                         initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" 
                                         bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController FirstViewController animated:YES];
```

FirstViewController.m

```
 self.SecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]
                                             initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" 
                                             bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.SecondViewController.totalNumberOfPlayers = self.selectedRow;
    [self.navigationController pushFadeViewController:self.SecondViewController];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

-(void)dealloc
{
  [SecondViewController release];
  NSLog(@"SecondViewController released");
}
```

When I run the app and switch from first to second view controller there is no NSLog input in console. This makes me think that the first view controller is not destroyed and the memory for it is not released.

Seems like [self.view removeFromSuperview] is not working well in this situation.

My question is how to release/destroy the FirstController ? It will be never used at the rest of the app.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are correct that view controllers in the stack are not released/destroyed. This is not a bug - it's by design because if you pop your current view controller it would need to display the underlying one again. The app doesn't know that you never intend to do that.

Your [self.view removeFromSuperview] doesn't work because that removes the view from the window (which has already been removed anyway when you pushed your second view controller) not the view controller from the stack (I think you may be confusing your views and your view controllers).

If you want to get rid of the first view controller, when you push your second view controller, instead of calling:

```
[navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Call this instead:

```
[navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:secondViewController] animated:YES];
```

That will replace the first view controller completely instead of just pushing the new one on top of it. The animation will be the same.

Be warned that the first view controller will be released immediately when you call the method above, so don't try to do anything to the first view controller after calling this or there's a good chance it will crash.

Update:

Here's how your app delegate setup code should look:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] init] autorelease];

FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstViewController animated:YES];
[firstViewController release];
```

Things to note:

1. Don't store the firstViewController in a property, or it won't be released when it's popped and dealloc still won't get called (you can delete the firstViewController) property.
2. Use lowercase for variable names, only capitalize class names
3. Always release or autorelease objects that you alloc/init in the same method where you create them - this will avoid Analyzer warnings (and avoid leaks).
4. You don't need to specify the nib file if the nib file name matches the view controller class name.

Nick

Comment: Thanks, Nick !

I have just two questions. I tried the code you suggest but dealloc method of the first view controller is not called. Also can I use that code in sequence ? What I mean to use [navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:thirdViewController] animated:YES]; in theSecondViewController, [navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:fourthViewController] animated:YES]; in third view controller and so on

Comment: You need to set the self.FirstViewController property to nil after you're finished with it otherwise it won't be released. You can use the setViewControllers: method as many times as you like but won't be able to use the popViewController: method to go back to a previous view unless you use pushViewController: to display the next one.

Comment: I would actually suggest that you don't store FirstViewController in a property - just use a local variable inside your function to create it and then push it onto the navigation controller, then release the local variable. The navigationController retains it while it's visible, so there's no need to store it in a property in your app delegate.

Comment: By the way, you should really use ARC - it looks like you're leaking objects in a few places, and using ARC will prevent that. Use Edit > Refactor > Convert to ARC to convert your project automatically. Also, try running the Product > Analyze tool to see where you are leaking objects.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions ! Actually Instruments gives no memory leaks, but analyze shows some potential. No one is from the code above.

Comment: There's a leak in app delegate when you create your first view controller because you [[alloc] init] it (retain count = 1) and then assign it to a retained property (which retains it again, retain count = 2) but you never release it. The Leaks tool only flags leaks when the last object reference is dropped, so when you set the property to nil and remove it from the view controller the retain count would still be 1 and you'd leak, but because you were never setting the property to nil, the leak never actually happened. The Analyzer is more reliable because it sees the leak before it happens.

Comment: By the way, did you know that [[SecondViewController alloc] init] is the same as [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; If you don't specify a nib name it automatically uses the nib with a name that matches the class name.

Comment: Thanks again Nick !
To avoid that leak I should add [FirstViewController release] after [navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:secondViewController] animated:YES], right ?

Comment: No you should add it after [navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:firstViewController] animated:YES]; - you should release the first view controller after you present the first view controller, not wait until you present the second. Or you could just use ARC and not have to worry about it!

Comment: I missed another couple of leaks - you need to autorelease the window and navigationController as well. I've updated the answer again. You shouldn't get any Analyzer warnings now.

Comment: @NickLockwood, setting the Navigation Controller viewControllers property has an unfortunate effect for me - console spits out a warning: Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

Apart from that, it works fine. Any ideas on how to suppress it?

Comment: It sounds like you may be setting the viewControllers array during another navigation transition (e.g. immediately after an animated push/pop of the navigation stack. You need to avoid manipulating the navigation stack whilst it is animating or you'll get this warning.